# Will .exe created using pyinstaller in 64 bit Python 3.7 on windows 10 work on 32 bit windows 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I have created a simple python program on a 64-bit Python 3.7 application on my Windows 10 and converted it to .exe using pyinstaller (onefile). Will it work on a 32-bit Windows 7. What are the system requirements in general (architecture, Windows version, RAM (the exe file is about 5 MB))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The way pyinstaller works is that it grabs a copy of your Python interpreter, your script, and all of the modules it needs, and builds a zip.  When you run it on another system, it creates a miniature Python installation by unzipping the zip.  If you have a 64-bit Python, then that's what it will embed.  The Windows version doesn't matter.  The RAM requirement is whatever Python requires.